# Maven standard convention for application properties file

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I hava a maven project of type jar. This is intended to be a standalone Java SE application running as a service. As usual it has his own app.properties file where properties like database connection information goes. So this is not a project ment to be uploaded to maven central, it's supposed to stay in my organization and it makes sense to have a property file alongside the jar.

I have seen many places where people just put the applicaiton properties file inside src/main/resources. But that gets copied inside the jar which is excatly what I dont' want.

I can manage to ask maven to copy what is inside for example `src/main/external-resources/*` to `target/*` so when I package the project I can easily do `java -jar ...` and the properties file is alongside the jar.

BUT that messes up with Netbeans which expects the properties file to be inside src/main/external-resources

1. How to make the app.properties file available in the classpath of the IDE when I debug it. Means I can access the file with `new File("app.properties")`
2. How to make that when I package my application that the app.properties file goes alongside the .jar file.

Basically I want to be able to debug my program in my IDE and use the properties file with `new File("app.properties")` and then when the application is packaged or assembled I want to do java -jar ... and that the application can still access it's property file (which is alongside the jar) with `new File("app.properties")`

Bonus: If this is not possible by convention and I have to work arround it, Why the .... haven't maven changed this already to this date?

Comment: Maybe  it worth checking: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html Also I would agree with @Seelenvirtuose.

Comment: Ok, I am using Eclipse, so I do not know, how to make Netbeans see this file when running there. In Eclipse, the four directories main/java, main/resources, test/java, and test/resources are on the build path and thus on the class path when running a main class. For such properties files, we put it into test/resources. So it is in the class path, as I told before. Regarding the packaging, I think, I have answered this.

Comment: Use the maven-jar-plugin  instead.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Eclipse and Netbeans works the same for this purpose. If app.properties is in classpath as you mention it I still can't access it throguh new File("app.properties"), I have to do new File("src/main/java/resources"). Then I need to exclude that properties file from the jar file and copy it alongside the jar. Is this the convention for this situation?

Comment: Hmmm ... you should never load _resources_ (and such a properties file is a resource to your application) with `new File(...)`. Always us the method `getResource()` of a class loader for this. So in your code you can load it via `loader.getResource("app.properties")`, relying on the fact that the resource is in the root of your class path.

Comment: I think you made the point to the right answer which is that the question itself was wrongly focused. If you can please elaborate a little in your answer and I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably many ways of achieving the desired output. Assume you have an app.properties with default values that should get deployed with your application. Assume further, that you have many libraries to ship with your application, too.

What we do in such a case is assembling a zip file with the following content:

```
<root>
  |
  +--- lib/
  |     |
  |     +--- [all your libraries here]
  |
  +--- application.jar (of course named as you want)
  |
  +--- app.properties
```

There is maybe also a properties file for configuring your logging framework, which you could also place into the root directory. Your application.jar then correctly refers to all JARs and the root dir in the Class-Path section of its manifest file.

This ZIP file can be assembled with the maven-assembly-plugin. At least, this is what we do. This could be done in an own project that only exists for this purpose. This project then contains the app.properties file with the defaults in a directory that you think is suitable.

If you want to test your project by running main classes directly from your IDE (like we do with Eclipse), you can got with an app.properties in the `src/test/resources` directory. This will usually be on the class path while running from an IDE, but will not end up in the JAR file. And it also is on the class path when running tests.

Does this fit your needs?

EDIT as per the request:

You should place the `app.properties` file into the project directory `src/test/resources`. This way, it will be in the class path when running main classes from the IDE (for testing purposes). This way it also will be in the class path of running tests with Maven.

Second, you should **not** load the `app.properties` file with `new File(...)`. Always use a class loader for this purpose, as this is the correct way to load resources in your program:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL appResourceURL = loader.getResource("app.properties");
```

Note, that you don't provide a path (or package, or whatever) when loading the resource. Just the file name. That is because the file itself is in the *root* of your class path. When running tests for example, this is due to the fact that it directly is located in `src/test/resources`.

Now you want to deploy your application. An application does not only consist of a main JAR file, but it also depends on many library JAR files and on some configuration files, such as the `app.properties` file, which you want to be placed *outside* the main JAR file.

The Maven philosophy is to only have one generated artifact. So to let this untouched, you could create a new project that has the purpose of creating a ZIP file for deployment. But you also can (I did that in many projects, too) adjust your project's POM to generate the JAR file and the assembled ZIP file.

The POM should contain the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Read about the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), it has many configuration options. The descriptor element refers to a descriptor file, which configures how the ZIP file will be assembled. You could also use some built-in configurations. Read the documentation.

A last step must be to configure the jar plugin so that the manifest contains a correct class path. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note, that I did place configuration files into a directory called config (only in the resulting ZIP). This then must be part of the class path.

If you afterwards extract the ZIP file to any directory, you can start your program with whatever method you like. Most likely it will be a runnable JAR or an executable (or maybe a script) will also be alongside your JAR.

Comment: I already know how to make it work outside the IDE I said that in my question. The problem is that netbeans sees the app.properties file in a different location than what the packaged jar does. Review my question I updated it to clarify what I really want

Comment: can you show my the pom that does what you say ? and how you configure the launcher in eclipse so that you application can access the properties file through new File("app.properties") ?

Comment: @DavidHofmann I updated my answer. Does this help? If not, I fear that I did not understand your problem very well.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the output of your project is your jar file itself. So you only include what goes inside the jar file(s) in src/*/resources.

When you say:

*How to make that when I package my application that the app.properties file goes alongside the .jar file.*

I would suggest (if I were in your situation) that you plug in the assembly plugin to create a distribution tarball/zipfile which includes your jar file, your properties file, and whatever more you need.

[Here's the basic information about it](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html).

**Update** (Note it is handcrafted, so watch typos):

Adding the assembly plugin to the pom:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Then adding the assembly descriptor in `src/assembly/dep.xml`:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>bundle</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <!-- ************************************************************ -->
      <!-- This dependency copies all  jar files    -->
      <!-- ************************************************************ -->
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
      <outputDirectory>lib/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*:jar:*</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
 <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <!-- ************************************************************ -->
      <!-- Copy the environment specific property files                 -->
      <!-- ************************************************************ -->
      <directory>src/main/external-config</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>app.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
 </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Furthermore, the eclipse launcher would have the working directory set to src/main/external-config if I had this specific requirements. It can be set explicitly in an eclipse launcher on the arguments tab.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense same as @Seelenvirtuose answer. The question is how to make the IDE access the properties file while running the app in debug mode through new File("app.properties") (note, NOT as a resource from the classloader) and then how to package it alongside the jar I can manage to do it

Comment: Yes, sorry I usually use eclipse. Doesn't netbeans have some way of configuring a launcher configuration?

Comment: can you show my the pom that does what you say ? and how you configure the launcher in eclipse so that you application can access the properties file through new File("app.properties") ?